# horizontal responsive layout

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I was trying to achieve a horizontal responsive layout here http://ragzor.com/neutron for like 5 hours now lol , I could do this using jquery but i believe thats using a screwdriver to do a hammer's job :) using floats just does not do anything and I also tried using position absolute and relative , absolute breaks the slides since they are using max-width(i guess this is the reason not sure tho!)

so what will be the best way to do this?

thanks alot!!!

Comment: Could we look at what you currently have?

Comment: did you try googlin a tutorial? http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/02/responsive-horizontal-layout/

Answer (score 0):

@Dinesh is right. You should start with some tutorials on Responsive Design. These are all almost guaranteed to contain CSS3 Media Queries. You can find an aggregate of Responsive Design tutorials here: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-tutorials/. Using `floats` can be tricky / dangerous when desiring a large amount of Responsive Design because floating elements removes them from the documents flow. Hope this helps!